# How can I Import a node module from a JS file in Laravel using Vite?

Tags: javascript, laravel, node-modules, vite

I am building a project using Laravel with Vite for my assets. I want to load a file located in the node_modules folder from a JS file :

```
Project
├── node_modules
├── public
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── my-file.js
├── vite.config.js
```

This is my `vite.config.js` file :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'node_modules/fathom-client/dist/fathom-client.esm.js' // The file I am trying to import
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

I am able to load it in a `view.blade.php` file like this :

```
@vite('node_modules/fathom-client/dist/fathom-client.esm.js');
```

However, I would like to import functions from the file in `my-file.js` located in the public directory as such :

```
import {
    load as faLoad,
    trackPageview as faPageView,
} from "the/module/";
```

I have tried making an alias in the vite config and importing the module without a relative path but that caused me errors in each case.

Comment: Have you found a solution on this?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately

Comment: I think you need to attach them to window in app.js. `window.faLoad = faLoad`